# Show two content types in same view

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

Drupal 8 newb here,

I have two basic types I need to show in my front page: There’s a “Restaurants” content type and a “Chefs” content type.

These are shown in my site like this:

[image: Site layout]

The types are unrelated, I just need to show them in the same page as featured.

I’ve found documentation on how to make blocks and views but nothing about mixed content, which seems to me like a common use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you want to list each type separate and not mixed, your only choice is to create two separate view blocks for each type. You could then add those view blocks to the header or footer of page view by adding a "view area".

Comment: I’d do exactly the same as @NoSssweat ... hey there, bonjour !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! exactly how I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use blocks: You can create a view with a page and an attachment. First from admin/structure/views/add, you create a view for content, selecting the content type to show and selecting *Create a page*.

> [image: screenshot]

Click on <kbd>Save and edit</kbd>.
On the next page, which shows the view settings, click on the <kbd>+ Add</kbd> button and select *Attachment*.

> [image: screenshot]

The next page will show the settings for the attachment.

> [image: screenshot]

The attachment shows nodes for the same content type the *Page* view does. The first step is changing that. Click on the *Content: Content type* in the filtering criteria.

> [image: screenshot]

On the top, change *For* from *All displays* to *This attachment (override)*, select the content type to show. Click on <kbd>Apply (this display)</kbd>.

The attachment still need to be attached to the *Page* view. On  *Attach to: Not defined* click on *Not defined*.

> [image: screenshot]

On the dialog box, select *Page* and click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

> [image: screenshot]

If you want the attachment to appear after the main content, change from *Attachment position: Before* to  Attachment position: After*. Then, click on <kbd>Save</kbd> to save the settings.

The view needs to be styled better (for example, selecting *Grid* as format instead of *Unformatted list*), but it shows two different content types on the same page.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did it almost the same except I created blocks instead of attachments as I had to manage lots of other fields